# Big number in an array - constructor

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, digit

In Java, I have to make a constructor of an array in which each digit of a big number will be a different char of this array.

This is the main class:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigNumber bn1 = new BigNumber(1500);
    BigNumber bn2 = new BigNumber("987349837937497938943242");  

    System.out.println("line 1: " + bn1);
    System.out.println("line 2: " + bn2);
}
```

I tried to make a constructor using a String but I'm not sure if it's good:

```
private String number;
private char[] n = null;

public BigNumber(String _number){
    number = _number;
    n = new char[number.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
        n[i] = number.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Or maybe there's a different way to do this?

Comment: I think that the for loop its ok. Dot be afraid to use them :)

Answer (score 1):

> "*I have to make a constructor of an array in which each digit of a big number will be a different char of this array."*

You can just do

```
n = _number.toCharArray();
```

which returns a character array of the String

```
private char[] n = null;

public BigNumber(String _number){
    n = _number.toCharArray();
}
```

---

If you want to print the BigNumber object as a `String`, you need to @Override the `toString()` method in the `BigNumber` class

```
public class BigNumber {
    ....

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Arrays.toString(n);
    }
}
```

The way you're currently printing won't print the array as you would expect. You need to override the `toString()` method to output the object as a `String` representation with your desired output format. My simple example just prints out the array as a String, though you can choose to format it any way you like. But keep in mind the method *must* return a `String`

Then you can do *this*

```
BigNumber bn2 = new BigNumber("987349837937497938943242");  
System.out.println("line 1: " + bn2);
```

---

**Also NOTE** : You *cannot* do *this*

```
BigNumber bn1 = new BigNumber(1500);
```

as the `BigNumber` constructor only take a `String` argument, where `1500` is an `int`. You *could* do *this*

```
BigNumber bn1 = new BigNumber(String.valueOf(1500));
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you wanted to accept an `int` as an argument to the constructor, you would need to create a separate constructor that takes an `int` argument. In which case you would also need to make the `int` a `String`, then get the character array. So you would have two constructors, one that takes a `String` and one that takes an `int`

```
public BigNumber(int number){
    String numString = String.valueOf(number);
    n = number.toCharArray();
}
```

Comment: Why he cannot overload the constructor ?

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVejar there's no reason he can't, but that defeats the whole purpose of creating a character array. I will still post an Edit though

Answer (score 0):

[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has a [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method that will give you what you want.

```
n = _number.toCharArray();
```

Of note, `toCharArray` returns a copy of the original string.  So, any changes you make to the array will not be reflected in the source string.